# osmbonuspack get KmlPlacemark Style

Tags: kml, osmdroid

In Osmbonuspack, I am displaying a KML on the OSM map. Now I am parsing the KML using KmlDocument. When I get a KmlPlacemark, how to get the "style" attribute of this KmlPlacemark? 
kmlPlacemark.mStyle is just a String variable.

Answer (score 0):

I found that KmlDocument object is used to get the Style like this:

```
Style style = kmlDocument.getStyle(kmlPlacemark.mStyle);
```